# Netbeans does not add new server after upgrade of Tomcat 7 to 8

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, netbeans

I upgraded my Tomcat from version 7.0.47 to version 8.0.0-RC5 (x86) and it was fine (I did the tests).

When I was do a new configuration onto NetBeans 7.4 to handle with Tomcat 8.0.0-RC5 it showed: The LocationServer Folder(CatalinaHome)specified is not valid.

I tried C:\Program Files\Apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC5 or C:\Program Files\Apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC5/conf and I haven't sucess.

I know the file tomcat-users.xml exist and my user and password is there.

I read some posts talking about to downgrade the Tomcat, but I'd like to execute some tasks before it. maybe setting some files... Could you please help me?

Marcos

Comment: You know that this is an alpha version of Tomcat right? Its a bit too much to expect Netbeans to already support Tomcat 8 for deployment, its pre-bleeding edge.

Comment: Yes, I know it. I'm using a lab installation and I'd like to do some tests.

Comment: I got it. I mean, I did the downgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I have added tomcat 8 to netbeans 7.4 with a seperate catalina base(netbeans catalina base) from my semi production environment (original installation).

Consequence of my solution:

1. Project creation will allow you to use JavaEE 6 only (JavaWeb Projects)
2. You only use JavaEE 7 if you are working with (JavaWeb)Marven projects but you will need Glassfish4 or later integrated with your netbeans installation. You use glassfish during project creation and then change server after project creation.

Steps (Option 1):

1. Install both tomcat 7 and tomcat 8 into one folder (Folder where you want tomcat 8 to be installed or is installed), suppose these folders are tomcat7 and tomcat8 respectively.
2. Change tomcat8 to tomcat8_ and tomcat7 to tomcat8 install the tomcat8 folder as one of your servers and name it appropriately (something like tomcat 8.0.1).
3. Rename the folders to their original names after installation, this will allow you to do normal tomcat7 functions using tomcat 8 installation

Option 2:

1. Follow steps 1 and 2 above
2. Create folder in (C:\Users\Bonron\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4\apache-tomcat-8.0.1.0_base) this will be used as your netbeans catalina base
3. Install server as in Option 1 but specify private Catalina base as created folder
4. Do step 3 of Option 1
5. Copy all folders in tomcat8 and paste into your private base (exclude bin and lib - unecessary)
6. Do not replace the newly created tomcat-users.xml but you need to replace server.xml, otherwise contact me if you prefer to edit it (invloves just commenting out one line)

Answer (score 0):

Try a dev build of NB 8.0. Regarding http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans_80_NewAndNoteworthy Tomcat 8 will be supported.

If you encounter an bug in this feature, please file an issue at https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/